# invalid quantifier javascript error on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm trying to replace a number in a string with another number using javascript. I have a long string that has the number 1 in it several times.  I need to replace the number 1 with 2 in every case except where 1 has another number on either side. I did a bunch of google searches for how to use regex (I'm totally new to regex) and I came up with this.

```
string.replace(/(?<!\d)1(?!\d)/,2);
```

Basically, I want the regex to match (and thus replace) every occurrence of the number 1 where it is surrounded by anything except another number. I don't want the match to include the surrounding characters--only the number 1.

I keep getting the invalid quantifier error in my firebug console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's this bit: `(?<!\d)`. There's no `(?<`, only `(?:`, `(?=`, and `(?!`.

JavaScript doesn't have look-behind, but I think you can work around it in this case, like this:

```
str = str.replace(/(^|\D)1(?!\d)/g, "$12")
```

That captures the character immediately prior to the digit, then echoes it back (`$1` in the replacement string) followed by the new content (`2`). The `^` near the beginning allows for the digit being the first character in the string.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ufaraq/4)

Breaking it down:

```
(^|\D)   Match either start-of-string, or a non-digit, and capture the result
1        Match the digit 1...
(?!\d)   ...but only if it isn't followed by a digit
```

And in the replacement, `$12` is *not* "replace with capture group 12" (which is what it looks like to me), but "replace with capture group 1 followed by the digit 2."

Comment: Is the colon the correct operator for the negative lookbehind?  I was reading on [link]http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html on how to do negative lookbehinds and he says to use the lt character.  I replaced it with the colon like you said and I no longer get the error, but it doesn't return any matches either??  I tried adding g after the final slash to match every occurrence and it still doesn't work. I'm clueless here.

Comment: @Jonathan: No, JavaScript doesn't have look-behind (only look-ahead, both positive and negative). The `?:` just denotes a non-capturing block.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks so much. Here's what I ended up with based on what you gave me: `var i = 1;
 $("#addshipmentobjecbutton").click(function(){
  if (i<=5) {
   var old_object = $('#shipmentobject').html();
   var new_object = old_object.replace(/(^|\D)\d(?!\d)/g, "$"+i+2);
   $('#shipmentobjects').append("<fieldset>"+new_object+"</fieldset>");
   i++;
  }
 });`

Comment: @Jonathan: The replacement string must *always* start with `$1`. Whatever you put *after* that will be what replaces the `1`. You need the `$1` at the beginning because it (potentially) contains the non-digit character in front of the `1`. Oh, and btw, for some reason I was really general in my version, but you did say specifically you wanted to match `1`, not just a one-digit number. Sorry about that, I've fixed it.

Comment: ok...so my comment above was an epic fail. :)  after reading your edit on the answer, I now understand what your code does. So I replaced my replace code with this `replace(/(^|\D)1(?!\d)/g, "$1"+(i+1));` and now it works. On each click of the button, the string is searched and replaced on each instance of 1 not surrounded by another digit, AND the replacement increments on each subsequent click. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Jonathan: Perfect! Glad that helped. Sorry I forgot to click "Save Edits" earlier (you were probably wondering why I'd said I'd edited it when I hadn't).